# Need javascript to rewrite visitors name

Tags: javascript, prompt

I need a way of java script writing a welcoming to them with their own name after them telling it using a java prompt or HTML box

I have already tried looking the solution up in different ways, but cant find any solution.

I just started learning java script, And i cant figure out how to do this

http://pastebin.com/X7vfFjba

Comment: *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to store the value obtained from the prompt in a variable and then output it to the console.

```
var name = prompt("What is your name");
console.log("Welcome " + name);
```

It is better to show the message through the `alert` box.

```
alert("Welcome " + name);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP didn't mean the console when they said "prompt".

Comment: Thank you very much, I will mark it as right when stackoverflow lets me, 11 minutes

Comment: @Juhana Could you go and visit the pastebin link?

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt very clear on what i was wanting, The pastebin link was what i thought it kind of would look like, And Sampriti gave me a response to what i actually wanted

Comment: ... Ok, fair enough. I just couldn't believe that the console would be preferred for showing messages to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- JavaScript and HTML codes by Quackit.com -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
function welcomeMsg(promptMsg)
    {
    visitorName = prompt(promptMsg, '');
    alert("Welcome " + visitorName + "," + "\n\n" + "You are currently visiting one of the best web development sites on the net! Hope you find Quackit useful!" + "\n\n" + "Hey " + visitorName + ", don't forget to recommend us to your friends!");
    }
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="welcomeMsg('What is your name?');" value="Read our Welcome Message!" />
</form>
```